# Is it safe to turn on windows update for AWS EC2 machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 windows machine running Windows Server 2012 R2.

I am having an issue with one application and I am suspecting that the machine does not have the latest .Net patches.

I looked into Windows Update and noticed it's turned off by default.  Can I turn it on and update the machine?  Right mow there are 20 important updates waiting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to install Windows updates (either automatically or manually).

Actually, it is recommended that you always update your Amazon EC2 instances to maintain the latest security patches.

They're just normal Windows machines. No need to handle them any differently to how you would normally maintain a Windows server.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the patch manager https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/getting-started-with-patch-manager-and-amazon-ec2-systems-manager/